# splitext in write is not giving the basename

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to split text to the basename as:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import os.path 
out.write(atoms[q]+" ")
out.write(str(os.path.splitext(atoms[q][0]))+" ")
```

which is yielding:

```
Mn7.pot ('M', '')
```

where obviously the full text is `Mn7.pot` as shown by the first one, and by splitext, I want the `'Mn7'`, (even better, if I can have without the enclosing `''`).

If I do this in terminal, using print, I am getting the correct result(almost) as:

```
 $python3
Python 3.3.2 (default, Mar  5 2014, 08:21:05) 
[GCC 4.8.2 20131212 (Red Hat 4.8.2-7)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os.path
>>> file="Mn7.pot"
>>> os.path.splitext(file)
('Mn7', '.pot')
```

please show me how I can achieve this is `write` function as well.

Answer (score 0):

If `atoms[q]` is `Mn7.pot` then `atoms[q][0]` is `M`.

You don't need the `str()` call and you don't need the `[0]`.